# Link views page to taxonomy term page

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

1. I have created a views block and page to display nodes based on term of a taxonomy vocabulary (contextual filter).
2. From this block I have a more link enabled and linked to the page.
3. Here how to make the views page path linked to corresponding taxonomy term pages?

Comment: give the path of the view as taxonomy/term/%

Comment: Yes, this would work. But I am trying to link to a clean URL

Comment: after adding that over ride the path by installing the pathauto module and define your patter there

Comment: ok I will add it as an aswer.

Comment: You can also override taxonomy pages per vocabulary - using views instead of default taxonomy page - using - http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Provide the path as taxonomy/term/%
2. Install the [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module and override the path using the required patterns.

Comment: When I do this, at the same time how do I print the Taxonomy title as page title? as it happens on the default Taxonomy term view.

Comment: by default it should display taxonomy title as page title if not in the contextual filter select "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS IN THE URL OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED
" select Override title and place %1

Comment: Yes, I did looked at how the contextual filter is configured on default Taxonomy term view, and did the same on my view it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the link manually to the footer section, your code could be something like this:

```
<a href="<?php print url('news'); ?>" class="bottom-block-button"><span><?php print t('Read More'); ?></span></a>
```