# Add taxonomy to Views page

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I am attempting to get a views page into a taxonomy term page using [this solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/57943/link-views-page-to-taxonomy-term-page) to no avail.

My taxonomy page is at [URL]/menu-tags/resource, so I made the Views page URL [URL]menu-tags/resource/resource-hub. The page doesn't show up despite having the settings set up in the pathauto config and the taxonomy checks out. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to build your own taxonomy term lists via views-driven output. One of these methods, which appears to be the one that you are working on, is to override the core taxonomy/term/% path with a view display. This "routing-level" override just ensures that all requests to a taxonomy/term/[id] page are handled by your view instead of the core term list callback. In order for this to work however, your view needs to use the **exact same path** as the core taxonomy term path (i.e. taxonomy/term/%), and implement a contextual filter for the term id. This path is independent of any path alias patterns you may have setup for your taxonomy terms. So if one of your term vocabularies is aliased with a pattern menu-tags/resource/[term-name], the actual Drupal path that views needs to respond to, and override, is still taxonomy/term/[id].

It's also worth pointing out that this technique has some drawbacks. Most notably you don't have the ability to define different view displays for different taxonomy vocabularies (as all vocabularies use taxonomy/term/% as their raw path by default). Because of this you may want to consider an alternative approach of using the [taxonomy display](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display) module. Instead of overriding just the term path, this module overrides the actual rendering of the term page itself, and therefore has a bit more flexibility. It's also fairly easy to setup, just check out the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1254878).